# jQuery ajax request, PHP returns false but no error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've used the **jQuery.ajax()** method on the client-side.

On the server-side the PHP script **`return false;`** - this normally triggered the **error** function to be executed on the client side. But at the moment this doesn't happen anymore. The **success** function is executed and the `data = ""`.

Shouldn't be the **jQuery.ajax()** method raise the **error** method if a PHP script returns false?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "././mail/contact.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    name: name,
    subject: subject,
    email: email,
    message: message
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Success message
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Fail message
  },
});
```

---

**Update:** Inside the server-side PHP script the **`mail();`** function is called. Does this one set the http status code perhaps to 500 if it fails ?

Comment: no. false will be considered as string. if you want to send error then send status code.

Comment: return false in server side php will not trigger error function in ajax call.Normally jQuery error function will trigger only if it have any difficulties in loading server side page

Comment: error function is triggered  when it fails to complete request. you should get your data in success function.

Comment: If you need to run `error` - you can pass 500 status code for example.

Comment: I got the mail(); function called inside the php script - does this one set the http status code perhaps to 500 if it fails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Fail message
    },
});
```

`error` callback function is called on HTTP errors, not on logical errors in your code. From [**the doc**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),

> error 
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) 
>   A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. **Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`. When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as `"Not Found"` or `"Internal Server Error"`**

Which means `error` callback function will get triggered if:

- You're not connected to any verified network
- The requested page is not found
- There's any internal server error
- Your AJAX request is taking too long to process
- AJAX request is somehow aborted etc.

So your question,

> *Inside the server-side PHP script the mail(); function is called. Does this one set the http status code perhaps to 500 if it fails ?*

No. Generally, even if your `mail()` function fails it won't set the HTTP status code to 500, unless of course if it's taking too long for processing, in that case you'll get a timeout error in the `error` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../../mail/contact.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        subject: subject,
        email: email,
        message: message
    },
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```